# Scraping website using getElementsByClassName --> wrong results

Tags: html, vba, ms-access, web-scraping, screen-scraping

I am trying to scrape the innerText of all classes with className = "disabled" in the following HTML Code snippet:
[HTML code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sB1Bn.png)

The code I am trying to realize this in MS Access (VBA) is as follows:

```
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

claimLink = "https://www.XXXXX.com/"


IE.navigate claimLink
    Do
       DoEvents
    Loop Until IE.ReadyState = 4

Set menuEnabled = IE.Document.getElementsByClassName("disabled")(0)


For Each Item In menuEnabled
    MsgBox (Item.innerText & " --> " & Item.className)
Next

IE.Quit

Set menuEnabled = Nothing
Set searchres = Nothing
Set IE = Nothing
```

...as a result though, I get all items in this list, and MS Access also says that the class Name of all items (Bibliographic data, Description, Claims, etc.) is "disabled".

Can anyone please tell me what's wrong at my Code? All I want it to return is "Description", "Claims" and "Cited Documents".

[These Grey items are the only items I want to be replied](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X32ag.png)

Thanks!
Kornelius

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears to need a short wait for elements to be updated. I am using a css selector combination to target the elements of interest.

```
.epoContentNav [class=disabled]
```

The `"."` is a class selector. It selects for elements with class name matching after the `"."` i.e. `epoContentNav`. The `" "` is a descendant combinator meaning what is on the right are children of what is on the left. The `[]` is an attribute selector which selects an element by the attribute named within. In this case I am using an `attribute=value` combination to also specify the class name must be `disabled`. The whole thing reads as find elements with class `disabled` that have a parent with class `epoContentNav`. It selects all the nav bar elements with class `disabled`.

Info on those selectors [here.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors)

```
Option Explicit    
Public Sub GetInfo()
    Dim IE As New InternetExplorer, i As Long, nodeList

    With IE
        .Visible = True
        .navigate "https://worldwide.espacenet.com/publicationDetails/claims?DB=&ND=&locale=en_EP&FT=D&CC=DE&NR=1952914A&KC=A&tree=false#"

        While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

        Application.Wait Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 2)

        Set nodeList = .document.querySelectorAll(".epoContentNav [class=disabled]")
        For i = 0 To nodeList.Length - 1
            Debug.Print nodeList.item(i).innerText, nodeList.item(i).getAttribute("class")
        Next
        Stop
        'Quit '<== Remember to quit application
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply!
I tried to implement your suggestions. But still, I only get a list of all class items in "epoContentLeft". Do you have any other idea?
Thanks! Kornelius

Comment: The URL is public: [link](https://worldwide.espacenet.com/publicationDetails/claims?DB=&ND=&locale=en_EP&FT=D&CC=DE&NR=1952914A&KC=A&tree=false#) Thank you in advance!

Comment: Wow, that was quick! Basically, I want to know if the items in tha NavList are enabled or disabled (greyed-out). Actually, I've just realized that - when looking at the source Code - in "Debugger" mode all items are actually declared as "disabled". But investigating the NavList itself in the "DOM Explorer", the items that are greyed-out are also set to "disabled". How can I get these values?  Thank you in advance!

Comment: Thank you, I did run it and I think it exactly does what it is supposed to do --> listing 9 items of the navigation list on the top left. What I want to know though is which item is greyed-out (not active) on the Website (here: Description, Claims and Cited Documents). In the "DOM Explorer" section - when I analyze the source Code - These three items are acually set to "disabled" and the others are not. In the "Debug" section though, all Items are set to disabled - this is why your Code Returns all nine items I guess.

Comment: Now, how can I get only the deactivated items in the Navigation list? Also see [here](https://imgur.com/a/9a5kdvD)

Comment: Hi, I just added a link to a Picture in my original post. I basically only want three disabled and Grey items to be returned. I am sorry for the inconvenience and so happy that you stick with me... Thanks!

Comment: PERFECT! Thanks a lot. Now I'll do my homework to understand what exactly is going on there.

Comment: Explanation added.